# Laravel templating, don't check if relation exists

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a relationship between two models which is define by :

```
class Appartement extends Eloquent {
    public function lang()
{
    return $this->hasOne('AppartementLang')->where('language_id', '=', '2');
}
}
```

So nothing big.

When I try to do something like :

```
    @foreach ($appartements as $appartement)
    {{$appartement->lang->title}}<br/>
    {{$appartement->lang->subtitle}}<br/>
    {{link_to('/appartements/'.$appartement->link_rewrite, Lang::get('Discover'))}}<br/>
@endforeach
```

And that the lang does not exists, then laravel throws an error, which is pretty logical.

I wanted to know if there is some magical way which would allow me not to automate the verification that the relation exists. Basically not turn it into a big "if exists then use" for each property of the class like that :

```
@foreach ($appartements as $appartement)
    @if($appartement->lang){{$appartement->lang->title}}<br/>@endif
    @if($appartement->lang){{$appartement->lang->subtitle}}<br/>@endif
    {{link_to('/appartements/'.$appartement->link_rewrite, Lang::get('Discover'))}}<br/>
@endforeach
```

Thanks for the advice on that.

Comment: So the link shows whether the title or subtitle exist or not? Or do you want to not display anything for that record if Lang doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure there are lots of ways to do it (or at least try)

There is this option to check for existing and supply default if none, that I think is new in 4.1 (or at least it is new to me):

```
@foreach ($appartements as $appartement)
  {{ $appartement->lang->title or "default if doesn't exist" }}<br/>
  {{ $appartement->lang->subtitle or "default text if doesn't exist" }}<br/>
  {{ link_to('/appartements/'.$appartement->link_rewrite, Lang::get('Discover')) }}<br/>
@endforeach
```

or you could try one of these three if statements if you don't want anything to display for that particular record depending on existance of `lang`...

```
@foreach ($appartements as $appartement)
  @if ($appartement->lang)
  // or maybe:
  // @if ($appartement::has('lang'))
  // or also maybe:
  // @if ($appartement->lang->count())
    {{ $appartement->lang->title or "default if doesn't exist" }}<br/>
    {{ $appartement->lang->subtitle or "default text if doesn't exist" }}<br/>
    {{ link_to('/appartements/'.$appartement->link_rewrite, Lang::get('Discover')) }}
    <br/>
  @endif
@endforeach
```